# ngModelChange and change events together not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a text-input where I do a single way binding along with a numberformatter pipe too.

I also have a (ngModelChange) => to eliminate the comma which is being added when using the numberformatter and a (change) event to process the calculation.

```
<text-input class="text-right" 
   [editable]="editableFlag" 
   [ngModel]="pAmount | numberFormatter" 
   (ngModelChange)="pAmount =($event).replace(',', '')" 
   (change)="valChanged($event,fundType, key)" > 
</text-input>
```

All works good in Chrome, however the (ngModelChange) doesn't seem to be working in IE11.

I've searched across other posts in SO, nothing helpful so far.

Can someone help?

Comment: Did you make sure that you have the latest polyfills on board?  https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: Guess, I do!.. Thanks for replying though!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it misses the double way binding on your variable.
What's happens if you put '[(ngModel)]=pAmount | numberFormatter' ?

Comment: Thanks Romain for the answer!. Making it as a two-way bounded value doesn't make any difference unfortunately.